# Blender BGE move mesh in the direction its facing

Tags: mesh, game-engine

I am trying to move the cube in the below image in the direction it is pointing. I have tried this before, but I could not find out how to move the cube with BGE. I have a good understanding of python, a moderate understanding of blender, and a basic knowledge of trig. (my OS is ubuntu)

Here is my .blend file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwFJHyT6aOp3VVdHUnVzNGdMMEU

[image]

Comment: (I'm using blender 2.77)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just activate the *L* in the motion actuator `MoveUpA`either for *Loc* or *Rot* or both as desired.

It is already active for most other actions, only the forward motion is deactivated (probably by accident)